# interface with events and commands - cannot signal event

Tags: nesc

I found it difficult to signal an event in nesC. Can anyone help?
(EDIT: I omitted MainC components in code below).

I have defined a simple interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    command uint8_t action();
    event void actionDone();
}
```

It has one action and one event.

What's more I have one component which provides MyInterface:

```
configuration MyComponentC {
    provides interface MyInterface[uint8_t id];
}
implementation {
    components MyComponentM;
    MyInterface = MyComponentM.MyInterface;
}


module MyComponentM {
    provides interface MyInterface[uint8_t id];
}
implementation {
    command uint8_t MyInterface.action[uint8_t id]() {...}
    ...
    event void bar() {
        signal MyInterface.actionDone[foo]();
    }
}
```

Event bar is from completely different interface. In this event I want to signal event actionDone with id == foo.

I have also "main" component:

```
configuration MyAppC {
}
implementation {
    components MyC as App;
    components MyComponentC as MC;
    App.MyInterface -> MC.MyInterface[unique("Hello")];
}

module MyC {
    uses interface MyInterface;
}
implementation {
    event void MyInterface.actionDone() {...}
}
```

But during compilation I get an error:

```
MyInterface.actionDone not connected
```

Where did I make a mistake? How to properly connect components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but in your App try referring to MyC via alias, i.e. instead of

```
MyC.MyInterface -> MS.MyInterface[unique("Hello")];
```

try

```
App.MyInterface -> MS.MyInterface[unique("Hello")];
```

[UPDATE]

As explained in [this link](http://mail.millennium.berkeley.edu/pipermail/tinyos-help/2005-January/007229.html), since you are using parametrized interface and that there is no guarantee that all 256 instances will be wired to something you need to provide a default implementation in MyComponentM module

```
default event MyInterface.actionDone[foo]() {
    return;
}
```

Comment: it's my mistake, there should be (and in my real code there is!) App instead of MyC. But this is not the reason...

Comment: I guess then it should also be `-> MC.MyInterface...`

Comment: Ok, once again it's my fault. It should be MC instead of MS. There may be some other small mistakes which I have made during retyping code here. But this is not the reason for the error `MyInterface.actionDone not connected`. It is not parsing error, or undefined symbols, but something 'deeper'. The problem is somewhere in interfaces and components wiring, but I don't know where.